# How to pre-fill the look-up column in a child list?

Tags: lookup-column

How to pre-fill the look-up column in a child list item based on the parent item, from whose form the child is being created?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, I would add a query string with the ID of the parent item to the destination url when you click the save button.  From the new form, you could parse the parent ID out and set the selected value of the lookup with that ID.

Comment: Can you please explain it with an example or a link? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Check this out. http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/10/29/setting-sharepoint-form-fields-using-query-string-variables-without-using.aspx